# Can I create a configuration file for a shell script?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, shell

Is it possible to create a `.sh` shell or `.command` file with a configuration file?

I need to backup websites via Terminal and be able to put some data to configuration files,
and have the shell execute it.

For example, the username, password, ssh id, et cetera.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh admin@host.com "tar cjvf webfilesbackup-date-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.bz2 public_html/"    
ssh admin@host.com "mysqldump -u user_admin -ppass database_1 > databasebackup-`date +%Y%m%d`-db.sql"
scp admin@host.com:webfilesbackup-date-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.bz2 ~/backup/
scp admin@host.com:databasebackup-`date +%Y%m%d`-db.sql ~/backup/
ssh admin@host.com "rm -f webfilesbackup-date-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.bz2"
ssh admin@host.com "rm -f databasebackup-`date +%Y%m%d`-db.sql"
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a file (e.g. `settings`)  with your settings as variables:

```
username='foo'
pass='bar'
website='baz'
database='yak'
```

Then source the file from your script and you will be able to access the variables:

```
. settings
echo $username     # <- this will print "foo"
```

---

Concerning your second "question", if you have multiple hosts you can just have multiple config files and source the one passed as an argument to your script. For example, create a config file called `site1`.

Call your script with `./backup.sh site1`

```
. $1               # <- this will load the file "site1"
echo $username     # <- this will print "foo"
```

With your backup script, this would mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $1
ssh admin@host.com "tar cjvf webfilesbackup-date-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.bz2 public_html/"
ssh admin@host.com "mysqldump -u $user -p$pass $database > databasebackup-`date +%Y%m%d`-db.sql"
# ... and so on
```

Comment: I wouldn't append ".sh", since it's not meant to be executed.

Comment: If open Terminal.app and write something like this backup -site1 i have lot of queries in config file(site2,site3) with different (ssh,pass) is it possible?

Comment: @macman `-site1` would be an argument to your shell script. If you post the shell script in your question, it'd be easier to answer.

Comment: here is a picture diagram  [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/vg3D4.jpg)

Comment: -site1 maybe the parameter

Comment: Yeah, we know that it's the parameter. Do you just want your script to load the `site1` config file whenever you pass `-site1` as parameter? If not, what exactly do you need? Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/385121/edit) your question to tell us more. Ideally, post your current script there.

Comment: nd its possible?

if open Terminal.app

and write something like this

backup -site1

i have lot of queries in config file(site2,site3) with different (ssh,pass)

Comment: @macman It is possible. But if you don't show us some of your code we'll never even be able to guess what you want. You keep reiterating  the same gibberish. Why do you say `backup -site1` when you mention `file(site2,site3)`? It'd be easiest to have one config file per site, as WakiMiko already posted in their answer.

Comment: where earn reputation? to post image with code

Comment: @macman You earn reputation by writing good questions and answers, which will get you up votes. You don't need to upload an image with code, but **post the actual code** as raw text. Just copy and paste it to your question, hit the code formatting button `{}`, and done.

Comment: now.. i dont know how to create te configuration file for (sites,accounts,path to download folder) please help me.

Comment: it maybe works? {scp $user:webfilesbackup-date-date +%Y%m%d.tar.bz2 ~/backup/} in config file> {$user = 'admin@host.com'} config file is . site.sh how to add this parameter to .command to passing the config file backup -site1

Comment: Thank you so much! i have the last question :
how to pass argument with[no number]  ex: backup en

Answer (score 0):

The other option is just to create a text file and use a while loop to access that file line by line.

Comment: it maybe works?

{scp $user:webfilesbackup-date-date +%Y%m%d.tar.bz2 ~/backup/}

in config file>
{$user = 'admin@host.com'}

config file is . site.sh

how to add this parameter to .command to passing the config file

backup -site1

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p Example.app/Contents/MacOS`
cp script.sh Example.app/Contents/MacOS/Example
```

...and that will work.  [This article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps) has more detailed instructions, including how to get custom icons.

You might also look to Automator or AppleScript Studio as ways to build applications that can run sanely, without having to do it by hand.

Comment: yes but,i searching solution
to manually writ  "backup -s1"  to terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
     # parse the ini like $0.hostname.conf and set the variables
     # place a $0.`hostname -s`.conf file in the same dir as your script
     # set here any VarName=VarValue
     # use ; for comments - you will get host independant conf file 
     # for your bash scripts - [examle usage :][1] 
     doParseIniFile(){
        eval `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*/=/g' \
            -e 's/;.*$//' \
            -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' \
            -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' \
            -e "s/^\(.*\)=\([^\"']*\)$/\1=\"\2\"/" \
           < $IniFile \
            | sed -n -e "/^\[$IniSection\]/,/^\s*\[/{/^[^;].*\=.*/p;}"`
     }
     #eof function doParseIniFile
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding your code-only answer a little to explain what it does?