# Create an executable from a shell script in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create a configuration file for a shell script?](https://superuser.com/questions/385121/can-i-create-a-configuration-filefor-a-shell-script)

I need to create an executable from shell (`.command`) in OS X, with parameters.

Example:

```
backup -s1
```

`-s1` is a configuration file with data (user, site, path where to backup, etc.)

`-s2` would be another setting.